# Representative for or of

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

> Claude Miller, a sales representative *for* our farm equipment products, is truly an asset to the company, having increased its annual profits by as much as 25  percent.

What is the difference between representative *for* or *of*? I've usually seen using *of*. In the sentence above, is it possible to use *of* instead of *for*, in that case what is the difference in the meaning?

Comment: There's no *semantic* difference between using ***for*** or ***to*** (or ***of, in, with*** and doubtless other possible prepositions), and it would be stretching a point to suggest that some are syntactically "valid" whereas others aren't. My guess is that ***of*** would be the most common choice in your exact context, but you could simply sidestep the issue (as I and many other native speakers might be tempted to do) by rephrasing to a "noun adjunct" usage: *...our farm equipment products sales representative*.

Answer (score 1):

Claude Miller is the representative **of** the company; his particular responsibilites are **for** farm equipment products.